# Subversion relocate introduces authentication issue

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a home development server running on Debian at which I installed Subversion years ago. My development client is Windows 7 with TortoiseSVN. The whole setup has been working fine for years, and it allows me to access SVN from anywhere on the web.

Since the server is behind a home connection I specifically configured it using dynamic DNS, so that I would not have to change my SVN setup each time my home IP changes. Unfortunately, the free service I was using for dynamic DNS is terminated. I switched to a new one, yet now I have to alter my configuration.

I have a working copy that still points to the old DNS, so I'm trying to use the "relocate" option in TortoiseSVN to set the new location of the repos on the server. This triggers an authentication dialog box at which I'm stuck.

I have only one svn user, let's call it "admin" for now. I can SSH into the server with this account so I know my password is correct. I did not change my server side authorization setup either. Here's the Apache configuration for the virtual host:

```
<Location /svn/repos>
  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath /data/svn/repos
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion"
  AuthUserFile /data/svn/users/passwords
  <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
  Require user admin
  </LimitExcept>
 </Location>
```

I'm accessing repositories from the TortoiseSVN client via http. There's no proxies in between. The users/passwords setup refered to above are untouched. All of this worked fine just two days ago, the only change is the DNS. Still it does not except my admin credentials, it just keeps coming back with that prompt. I cleared the cached authentication data in TortoiseSVN but that does not help either.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to waste your time, I figured it out: my old DNS was a https address whilst the new one I was trying was http. Since I configured Apache to only allow svn over https, authentication failed.